# Reference request: self-adjointness of complex differentiation operators

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the complex differentiation operators (or Wirtinger derivatives)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right),$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right),$$
acting on real-differentiable functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.

**Question:** Are either of these operators symmetric with respect to the inner product on $L^2(\mathbb{C})$?

*Comment:* It seems to me that one can prove this using Green's theorem, but somehow I've not seen this discussed much; maybe I'm not looking in the right places. A reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are these creation operators in QM? It seems as such. If so, the answer is YES, since they are symmetric given the Hermiticity of the system

Comment: PS: Reference Quantum Theory by David Bohm

Comment: The operators don't map $L^2(\mathbb{C})$ to itself since the weak derivative of an $L^2$ function is not necessarily in $L^2$. The operators do map $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to itself. In this case, integration by parts yields that for any $u, v \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, 
$$(\partial_x u, v) = \int \partial_x u \overline{v} = -\int u \partial_x \overline{v} = -\int u \overline{\partial_x v} = -(u, \partial_x v).$$
Hence on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $\partial_x^* = -\partial_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these operators are not symmetric on $L^2(\mathbb C)$. I'll identify $L^2(\mathbb C)$ with $L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ (complex-valued functions). If $u,v\in C_c^1(\mathbb R^2)$, then integration by parts gives
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\overline{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}\right)v\,dx\,dy=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial \bar u}{\partial y}\right)v\,dx\,dy=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\bar u\left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy.
$$
In other words, $-\partial_{\bar z}\subset (\partial_z)^\ast $ or $ i\partial_{\bar z}\subset (i\partial_z)^\ast$, when the operators are defined on $C_c^1(\mathbb R^2)$.